# Changing color definition in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, color, arcgis-10.8

Using ArcMap 10.8.1 for desktop. I believe the definition I'm looking for is "Names" according to this ArcMap article [on working with colors](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/styles-and-symbols/working-with-color.htm). Currently, when I select the color drop down or color box on a shapefile, the RBG color selector pops up.

[image: RBG Color Selector]

What I'm used to and what I like is when I click the color drop down and this color selector pops up:

[image: Names Color Selector]

I know I can access the RGB color selector by clicking the More Colors button on the second color selector, but I don't know how to prevent it from showing up first. I believe the issue is changing the color definition that the program is reading but I don't know how to change that within the settings.

Comment: Are you saying the Color Selector dialog which you show in your first image is appearing instead of the panel of colours (your second image) and you want the panel to appear first?

Comment: @Hornbydd I want the second image to appear when I click the color drop down. Right now, the first image is what pops up when I click the color drop down.

Comment: Maybe that is new functionality implemented in 10.8? I cannot verify that as as I have 10.7 and for me when I click on the colour button I get the panel not the select dialog. It would be good if other users can verify the same behaviour?